# PageMenu Swift 3 Scroll sometimes doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift3

I have in my app three pagemenu in different parts of the app, sometimes 2 of these has a bug in the scroll that stops to change the views in the pagemenu. On the other hand, there is one pagemenu that it doesn't shows any of these problems. Any thoughts in this?

```
self.pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
self.pageMenu?.delegate = self
self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
self.view.addSubview(self.pageMenu!.view)
self.pageMenu?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: add animation code also.

Comment: @KKRocks if i remove the animation code then too facing the same issue.

Comment: you need to add  that code in question here .

Comment: check this link may this help you : https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu/issues/334

Comment: there is no solution in that page.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu/issues/338 Solves the issue by changing the currentOrientationIsPortrait in viewDidLayoutSubviews() in CAPSPageMenu.swift from UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait -> UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait